# Weird line showing up in Internet Explorer on Vista

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

A client of mine is saying that there is a line showing up in Internet Explorer on Vista. I only have Mac and XP machines so I can't see what she sees...

I've attached a screen shot she sent me:

http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/1296/internetexplorervista.jpg

The website address is: http://www.sodababy.com.au/

Any ideas what could be causing this? I checked it in IE 7 and 8 on XP which I would have thought would have rendered the page the same as Vista but it looks fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a 1px gap between the top border PNG (images/content_top.png) and the main body of the table to me.

Works for me on IE8 on XP, so I can't suggest anything other than the usual suspects like padding, font size and borders.